# Windows phone getting nearby latitude and longitude within 6 Kilometer based on my lat and long

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dictionary, latitude-longitude, here-api

people with the same app, register their location every time they open the app,
people that register the location within a 6 Kilometers can see each other based on what my app does.
I'm not using a map, just lat and long values, but its okay for a demo, 
so is there any algorithm that can do this ?
please help me ! 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little while ago this would have involved a lot of trigonometry. With the latest version of .NET however you can use the [GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
double distance = myLocation.GetDistanceTo(yourLocation); // metres
```